# Does svnadmin verify have an exit code of 1 on failure to verify?

Tags: svn

I'm writing a script to run verify on all of our repos on a scheduled basis, possibly every day. I'm running it with the -q option (quiet), and I'm trying to figure out how to detect if the verification was successful. There is nothing in the docs regarding exit codes, or what will get output if there is a failure. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SVN_ROOT=#root directory for repositories#
for name in $SVN_ROOT/*;
do
    start_time=`date +%s`
    REPO_NAME=$(basename $name);
    echo "--------------------"
    echo "Verifying $REPO_NAME"
    svnadmin verify $name -q
    end_time=`date +%s`
    run_time=$((end_time-start_time))
    echo "Verification took $run_time seconds"
    echo "--------------------"
    echo
done
```

Can we simply check the exit code of `svnadmin verify` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check return code of the command.

For example if a revision file is missing:

```
svnadmin verify ./fail-test/ > test.log
* Error verifying repository metadata.
svnadmin: E160006: No such revision 16

echo $? # -> 1
```

On a valid repo:

```
svnadmin verify ./ok-repo/ > test.log
echo $? # -> 0
```

You can test `$?` or save it to a variable.

Other approach would be to redirect stderr to a file and check its size later.

```
# this could be a loop
svnadmin verify fail-test > >(tee -a fail-test.out.log) 2> >(tee -a fail-test.err.log >&2)
svnadmin verify ok-repo > >(tee -a ok-repo.out.log) 2> >(tee -a ok-repo.err.log >&2)
# ...

# check size of errors
ls -l *.err.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If verification is successful you will not get any output at all. So check for that is, nothing should be written on terminal or nothing is returned.

Now failure can be anythings. But it always starts with

```
* Error verifying repository metadata.
svnadmin:
```

The one I have commonly encountered are
Looks something like this:

```
* Error verifying repository metadata.
svnadmin: E160006: No such revision 2
```

```
* Error verifying repository metadata.
svnadmin: E200014: L2P index checksum mismatch in file common-model_error/db/rev
s/0/2:
   expected:  889bad2c5c202537b7cba500084dce5a
     actual:  1858b46dd6554ef73bf8e0076e490802
```

You can get full information from the file `svnadmin_tests.py` from the svn source code.

Comment: It's not true that there is no output at all. There is only no ouput if you specify -q for quiet, otherwise it outputs info on every revision it checks.

Comment: Also, looked through svnadmin_tests.py, and it does not test "svnadmin verify"

Comment: I though the question was about -quiet mode only. -quiet mode doesnt output anything at all when successful. Yes there are whole sets of test for svnadmin. Functions to look for in the file are `verify_keep_going` and `verify_keep_going_quiet` and some more.

Comment: The only reliable way to do it is to know if svnadmin verify has an exit code of non-zero on failure. Parsing output is very kludgy. I don't know why it's not specified on the man page.

Comment: Actually it is not even documented in code. So it is highly unlikely to be in the manual page.

Comment: But anyways it is easy enough to check for no outputs and that is what i have in my setup,